# How to get href value and a th value from a table at the same time

Tags: php, html

I am having one table with many `<tr>` tags. In each `<tr>` , there are 4 `<td>` tags. In the 1st `td`, i am having one `<a>` tag, now I need to store the `href` value and the 3rd `<td>` value in an array.

Here is my code

```
      <tr> 
          <td><a href="http://www.example.com">Some name</a></td>
          <td>2009</td>
          <td>United States</td>
          <td> abc, xyz</td>
      </tr>
       ---------------------
       ---------------------

      <tr> 
          <td><a href="http://www.example10.com">Some name</a></td>
          <td>2010</td>
          <td>India</td>
          <td> abc, xyz</td>
      </tr>
```

Now, I am collecting all the href values, I dont know how to get the 3rd td value and store in the array at the same time. My code for collecting href's is

```
        $d = new DOMDocument();
        @$d->loadHTML( $contents );
        $a = $d->getElementsByTagName("a");
        $i = 0;
        foreach ( $a as $element ) {
           $element->getAttribute('href');
        }
```

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi if u only want to push the 1st and 3rd values of a row u can use  ":odd" selector do the task and push the consecutive values in array

Answer (score 0):

### Basically

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML( $contents );
//get 1 table only
$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName("table")->item(0);
//$nodeA = $node->getElementsByTagName('a');
$nodeTr = $node->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(2)

//foreach ( $nodeA as $element ) {

      //echo $element->getAttribute('href');
//}
echo $nodeTr->nodeName,':', $nodeTr->nodeValue;
```

Comment: I already got the href values, I need to retrieve the 3rd td value. Please check that

Comment: use `$node->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(2)`

Comment: Hi Sushant, where can i write this $node->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(2)

Answer (score 0):

use this into ur `foreach` loop

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML);
```

O/P : United States,India all details which is in 3rd `TD`

Comment: Hi Ashish, Please give me any php code which stores both href value and 3rd td value

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the suggestions. I got the expected output finally.

```
        $d = new DOMDocument();
        $d->validateOnParse = true;
        @$d->loadHTML($contents);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
        $table = $xpath->query("//table/tr");
        foreach ($table as $row) {
         $a_val = $row -> getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');;
         $td_val = $row -> getElementsByTagName('td')->item(2)->nodeValue;
         $data.= "{$a_val} - {$td_val}\n";  
        }
```